# Create a new column with partial name from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have five datasets that I have added a 'Year' column to, like this:

```
newyork2014['Year'] = 2014
newyork2015['Year'] = 2015
newyork2016['Year'] = 2016
newyork2017['Year'] = 2017
newyork2018['Year'] = 2018
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a more Pythonic way of doing this, perhaps with a function?  I don't want to change the actual dataframe into a string though, but I want to "stringify" the name of the dataframe.  Here's what I was thinking:

```
def get_year(df):
    df['Year'] = last four digits of name of df
    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to adjust a little bit when you create the dataframe , need assign a `name`

```
newyork2014.name='newyork2014'

def get_year(df):
    df['Year'] = df.name[-4:]
    return df
get_year(newyork2014)
Out[42]: 
           ID  Col1  Col2  New  Year
2018-06-01  A    10   100  0.5  2014
2018-06-02  B     5    25  2.1  2014
2018-06-03  A    25    25  0.6  2014
```

Comment: This works but it defeats the purpose of creating the function since I'd have to manually manipulate all of the dataframes with the .name before sending the dfs through the function.